# Deploy succeeded but android app is not launched in xamarin forms on vs 2019 latest version?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Last week i was updated latest version of visual studio. there is no error in existing source. but app is only deployed, not launched in connected device or simulator. this issue will be occurred only in latest version of vs2019. it will be working good in previous version of vs2019. (latest version 16.8)
if you know about this issue, please let me know , how to solve that?

Comment: Try to delete the folder bin and obj then clean and rebuild the project .

Comment: the same happened to me in a similar upgrade, I just closed both VS and Emulator, I think I had to rebot my machine and then started working again